# Implementing threads for seperate routes in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to implement a distinct thread for each route in apache camel.I do not want to use a thread pool or async as I want my process to remain synchronous.Could I please get a code example for the same in java DSL format.

Comment: Please edit your question with more information; http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: I have two routes implemented in my code.I would like two routes to be handled by two different threads.How to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each route uses its own thread, unless a route is using the direct component (http://camel.apache.org/direct), which will re-use the caller thread.

For example having 2 routes

```
from("file:foo").to("bean:blah");
from("jms:queue:bar").to("bean:great")
```

Is 2 routes, and each route uses its own thread.

On the other hand the following 2 routes

```
from("file:foo").to("bean:blah").to("direct:bar");
from("direct:bar").to("bean:great")
```

Then the 2nd route being a direct endpoint, will re-use the caller thread, from the 1st route, when the 1st route routes the message to it, using: .to("direct:bar")

Comment: But from what I saw from("file:") and from("jms") run sequential. Is there a way to have them both run in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [camel-direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) to have to a single-threaded, synchronous request/response route...